# Dynamically alter image within a div through conditionals

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am working on a website that uses purely Django, but I want one of two images to appear under a conditional, [Exactly like this VueJs example](https://tech.io/playgrounds/5598/conditional-statement-in-vue-js).

Is this possible without a frontend framework, if so what is the best approach to get it done?

Comment: Your question is unclear. It _is_ possible without a frontend **framework** (such as Vue.js), but it is not possible without using any front end code at all. You can implement the same functionality using plain Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way in Vanilla Javascript!

```html
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="img1.jpg" id="image" alt="">
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var img = document.getElementById('image');
    if (condition){
      img.src = "img2.jpg";
    }
  </script>
</html>
```